# Annoying black line between two images in html

Tags: html, css

I met a problem that there is a black line exist my html page but I didn't have any code for it

[image]

The part I use red line to draw a circle on it. There is a black line.
Here is my html code.

```
<div class="mid">
    <a href="@Url.Action("WesternCuisine", "Home")">
        <img src="~/Image/western_cuisine.png" style="width: 40%; height: 40%;" />
    </a>
    <a href="@Url.Action("ChineseCuisine", "Home")">
        <img src="~/Image/chinese_cuisine.png" style="width: 40%; height: 40%;" />
    </a>

    <div class="cfc-container">
        <h1 class="main-caption">&nbsp; Your precious <br />&nbsp; Feedback is our <br />&nbsp; Motivation to be better <br /><button type="button" class="main-button" onclick="window.location.href='/Home/Feedback';"><strong>Learn More</strong></button> </h1>
    </div>
</div>
```

And my css code

```
.mid { 
    margin-top: 0px;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    justify-content: center;
    text-align: center;
}

.cfc-container {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 80%;
    padding-top: 30px;
    padding-bottom: 30px;
    margin-top: 5px;
    margin-bottom: 30px;
    color: inherit;
    border: 1px solid;
    background-color: white;
    background-image: linear-gradient(to right,rgba(228,241,254,1),rgba(255,255,255,0.2)), url(../Image/customer_service.png);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: right;
}
```

I dun know how to delete that black line even I make `border: none` also cannot.

Comment: Share your URL if you have

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is because of the default behavior of  tag - text-decoration,

```
.mid a {
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

```css
.mid { 
    margin-top: 0px;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    justify-content: center;
    text-align: center;
}

.mid a {
   text-decoration: none;
}

.cfc-container {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 80%;
    padding-top: 30px;
    padding-bottom: 30px;
    margin-top: 5px;
    margin-bottom: 30px;
    color: inherit;
    border: 1px solid;
    background-color: white;
    background-image: linear-gradient(to right,rgba(228,241,254,1),rgba(255,255,255,0.2)), url(../Image/customer_service.png);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: right;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html> 
<body>

<div class="mid">
    <a href="@Url.Action("WesternCuisine", "Home")">
        <img src="https://thewindowsclub-thewindowsclubco.netdna-ssl.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/01/Password-Spoofing.jpg" style="width: 40%; height: 40%;" />
    </a>
    <a href="@Url.Action("ChineseCuisine", "Home")">
        <img src="https://thewindowsclub-thewindowsclubco.netdna-ssl.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/01/Password-Spoofing.jpg" style="width: 40%; height: 40%;" />
    </a>

    <div class="cfc-container">
        <h1 class="main-caption">&nbsp; Your precious <br />&nbsp; Feedback is our <br />&nbsp; Motivation to be better <br /><button type="button" class="main-button" onclick="window.location.href='/Home/Feedback';"><strong>Learn More</strong></button> </h1>
    </div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 4):

This is underline of first `<a>` tag.
Just apply `text-decoration: none` property to `<a>` tags in this block.

Answer (score 2):

kindly add below code in your css

```
a:-webkit-any-link
{
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

That black line in the underline of `a` tag. To remove it just use `text-decoration: none`, like this:

```css
.mid > a { 
  text-decoration: none;
}

.mid {
  margin-top: 0px;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: center;
  text-align: center;
}

.cfc-container {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 80%;
  padding-top: 30px;
  padding-bottom: 30px;
  margin-top: 5px;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
  color: inherit;
  border: 1px solid;
  background-color: white;
  background-image: linear-gradient(to right, rgba(228, 241, 254, 1), rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2)), url(../Image/customer_service.png);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: right;
}
```

```html
<div class="mid">
  <a href="@Url.Action(" WesternCuisine ", "Home ")">
    <img src="~/Image/western_cuisine.png" style="width: 40%; height: 40%;" />
  </a>
  <a href="@Url.Action(" ChineseCuisine ", "Home ")">
    <img src="~/Image/chinese_cuisine.png" style="width: 40%; height: 40%;" />
  </a>

  <div class="cfc-container">
    <h1 class="main-caption">&nbsp; Your precious <br />&nbsp; Feedback is our <br />&nbsp; Motivation to be better <br /><button type="button" class="main-button" onclick="window.location.href='/Home/Feedback';"><strong>Learn More</strong></button> </h1>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: #mid > a -> i hope you need to refer .mid, because mid is a classname not id.

Comment: Owhhh, I solved it. Thank you for the kindly reply.